# Ramified locus is the support of $\Omega_{X/Y}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

(From Shafarevich) Let $f: X\to Y$ be a finite map of irreducible varieties, and $Y$ is normal. $f$ is unramified over $y\in Y$ if the number of inverse images of $y$ equals the degree of the map. Otherwise, we say that $f$ is ramified at $y$, or
that $y$ is a ramification point or a branch point of $f$. the set of branch point is a closed set; it is called
the branch locus or ramification locus of $f$.

I wonder why the ramified locus is the support of $\Omega_{X/Y}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general setting, the ramification locus is defined to be the support of $\Omega_{X/Y}$, see for instance [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/024O). This is important when we're working in the general world of schemes - there are morphisms of schemes which are finite of degree $d$ and unramified but not all fibers consist of $d$ points: $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Q[T,T^{-1},Y]/(Y^d-T) \to \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Q[T,T^{-1}]$ is unramified of degree $d$ (even etale!), but the fiber over $(T-1)$ has one point for every divisor of $d$. One should also clarify that the ramification locus of a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is on $X$, while the branch locus is it's image under $f$ (and therefore lies on $Y$).

In this special case where $X,Y$ are irreducible varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$, we'll show that the closed points $x\in X$ with $(\Omega_{X/Y})_x \neq 0$ are exactly those points so that $f(x)$ has $<d$ preimages. Let $y\in Y$ be a closed point, and consider the inclusion $i:\{y\}\to Y$. Taking the base change $i':X_y = X\times_Y \{y\}\to X$ we see that $(i')^*\Omega_{X/Y} \to \Omega_{X_y/\{y\}}$ is an isomorphism (by [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01V0), for instance), and by the properties of the pullback, we can compute stalks of $\Omega_{X/Y}$ by computing stalks of $\Omega_{X_y/\{y\}}$ at the appropriate point.

To compute the stalks of $\Omega_{X_y/\{y\}}$ at each point in $X_y$, we first note that $X_y$ is the spectrum of a $k$-algebra $A$ which has dimension $d$ as a $k$-vector space. This implies that $A$ is Artinian, so it's a finite product of Artinian local rings $A_1\times\cdots\times A_m$ with $m\leq d$. If $m=d$, then $A_i\cong k$ for all $i$, and it's easy to see that the stalk at each of these points is zero. Conversely, if $m<d$, then one of the $A_i$ has a non-zero maximal ideal. But the maximal ideal of an Artinian local ring consists of nilpotent elements, and for any nonzero nilpotent element $x$, we have that $dx$ represents a nonzero class in $\Omega_{A_1/k}$ and therefore a nonzero class in the stalk of $\Omega_{X/Y}$ at the point corresponding to the maximal ideal inside $A_1$.

Comment: Your proof is based on scheme, how can I do this in terms of the (non-abstract) variety, i.e. the zero locus? In that setting, the $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is given by $\Omega_{\mathcal{O}_X/f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y}$, and it seems that your method can not apply.

Comment: That's a pretty non-standard definition of $\Omega_{X/Y}$. You should prove that this equivalent to the standard definition (or adopt the standard definition) and then everything will be alright. If you're talking about sheaves like $\Omega_{X/Y}$ then you're already dealing with (a restricted case of) schemes, so I don't understand what you mean when you say "non-abstract variety".

Comment: I think this definition is equivalent  to the standard definition in the  sense of: $f^{-1}$ is adjoint to $f_*$ in the sense of sheaf of topological spaces and $f^*$ is adjoint to $f_*$ in the sense of category of module sheaf. And the standard definition $\Delta^*(F/F^2)\cong \Omega_X/f^*\Omega_Y$.

Comment: I wonder why the definition $\Delta^*(F/F^2)$ can work on the varieties which are zero locus? These varieties are not schemes (at least we need to add the prime ideals to them. Do you mean the scheme of the mSpec?

Comment: Everything in this post will work assuming you actually know how to make $\Omega$ do the things it's supposed to do. It seems to me like your confusions about how to make $\Omega$ work in different contexts are not specific to this question and that you should deal with them in a separate post.